# Thunderbird How compose a message in new tab?

Tags: thunderbird

On [Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/), when I press `reply` or `new message` a new window is poped up to write a message rather than the main window. When I press `reply` button for the same mail, multiple independent reply windows are open, which leads a confliction.

**[Q]** Is it possible to open those windows to reply to a mail in a new tab instead of a new window?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to this [issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=449299), it's still not implemented.

Looks like you haven't been able to do this for quite a long time..

Comment: Ah :-( I will get back to using classic gmail.com than